# How should I delete part of string from beginning to first space?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

I'm using C++/CLI and I was trying to delete part of string from beginning to first space for a long time.

My code that doesn't work is:

```
String^ ns = gcnew String("Hello world!");
int temp1 = ns->IndexOf(" ");
int temp2 = ns->Length;
for (int i =temp1 +1; i < temp2; i++) {
    ns+= ns[i];
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Also, think a little bit about what the `+=` operator does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you count where is the first space, then use this function?

```
str = str->Remove( CoordsStart , CoordsEnd-CoordsStart );
```

Answer (score 0):

You said from beginning to first space but it isn't what your program seems to be doing.
is :

```
String^ ns = gcnew String("Hello world!");
int temp1 = ns->IndexOf(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < temp1; i++) {
    ns[&] = " ";
}
```

what you look for ?

Comment: This removes part of string from beginning to first space, the program is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is best.

```
string ns ="Hello world!";
int temp1 = ns.IndexOf(" ") + 1;
ns = ns.Substring(temp1);
//Console.WriteLine(ns);
```

Comment: This is not simple `string`, it's `String^`